# Collection view first 3 item should be static

Tags: ios, swift, static, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view and in that first 3 item should be static and after that dynamically will add.

Check my below code :-

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //
    return 20
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    //

    // Configure the cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier,
                                                  for: indexPath) as! AddProductInGroupCell
    //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.4
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 2

    if(3 > indexPath.row)
    {
        cell.ProductImage.image = UIImage(named : "folder.png")
        cell.lableProduct.text = arrCellsLabel[indexPath.row]

        cell.imageDotted.isHidden = true
        cell.imageLike.isHidden = true
    }

    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

when run the app,First time it is coming properly(3 static cells), but when we scroll down and coming to up again that 5 cells showing static.
What to do ?
Thanks

Comment: your condition is wrong brother

Comment: Why condition is wrong?

Comment: but it will show only two.

Comment: if(indexPath.row >= 0 && indexPath.row < 2)
{ //write your static cell} 
else { // your data cell }

Comment: But it is less then 2

Comment: See I have to show first 3 cells static and while scrolling also it is changing.
I checked with your condition.

Comment: if(indexPath.row >= 0 && indexPath.row < 3) { //write your static cell} else { // your data cell }

Comment: You don't have an `else` statement to set the cell properties for the dynamic items

Comment: If you don't mind Can you please correct answer for my Question?

Comment: Please check my updated question.

Comment: Your condition is correct but give the "else" part as well.

Comment: Yes I am giving else part also.
But after scrolling it's Showing the problem as I mentioned above.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the  cell reused, some of code maybe like this :

```
 if(3 > indexPath.row)
{
    cell.ProductImage.image = UIImage(named : "folder.png")
}
else
{
cell.ProductImage.image = UIImage(named : "application.png")
}
```

Comment: Actually I was not able to get correctly.
But assign a new image is solved my doubt.
Thanks